# Resize margin-top/bottom proportional to screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple rows of elements that i want to align vertical so that on different resolutions, the first screen (without scrolling) would be the same for each of them.

Luckly, i have some limits that i have to respect 800px and 1200px (vertical resolution). So only between those two values my margins have to increase/decrease proportionaly. If bigger or smaller than that interval the screen remains as it is to one of those limits.

Unfortunely, based on requirements i can't use media-queries or javascript for calculating this, so it has to be a pure CSS solution.

Is there a way of doing that? Without affecting height, width or left/right margins of the elements.

Or is there a javascript way of modifying that without injecting inline CSS property? I haven't heard of that but could it be possible to modify CSS files?

**EDIT** A non-table solution would be prefered.

Comment: And why can't you use javascript for this?

Comment: Customer's requirments. And media-queries, sorry. I'll edit my question ;)

Comment: @user2165193 Customers shouldn't make decisions about *your* work. They should hire you to make that kind of decisions for them.

Comment: Show us the html/css you have now

Comment: Media queries are pure CSS too.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I don't have any. It's part of my initial research, to answer to customer's requirments. And also i would be constructive to see an answer.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen When the customer is a self-named SEO guru and a tehnical educated person i don't have many choices. I tried to argue for that but first i want to see if it's possible, but as far as i know it's not. But it would be constructive to see if it's actually possible.

Comment: @Starx: the ideea befind not wanting media-queries is that i set fixed margins for out-range resolutions, but i dont know if it's possible to obtain a transitive result between those two resolution without writing 400 media-queries. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No javascript ? The only markup i see able to achieve this (**divide a page vertically + evenly**) is a `<table>`

I [fiddled an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpr3m/)

You will have to trigger height of 100% on body and html first,

```
html, body {
    height:100%
}

<table style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:green;background-color:pink">a&nbsp;a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:blue;background-color:aqua">b&nbsp;b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:red;background-color:cyan">r&nbsp;r</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Play with this, test it out to see if this solution suits your situation.

Otherwise, if you intent to use javascript, you can check out '[not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)' **calc()** in css3

Comment: It suits the question, but not the requirments. Sorry for not adding that in my question. But anyway a interesting solution :)